# Internal name swift 2.0+?

Tags: ios, swift

Before update to swift 2.0+ it worked. Now there is no internal parameters?

How should I change it then to let it work correctly?

I found out that I need to delete "func" and "#" but it didn't help D:

[image: MyCode]

```
func previewFile(#path: NSIndexPath) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    self.fileIsLoading = false
    let previewQL = QLReaderViewController()
    previewQL.dataSource = self
    previewQL.delegate = self
    previewQL.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    self.filepath = path
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(previewQL, animated: true)
}
```

So i did so ... 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSevS.png)

But if i delete this "path" would it work correctly? Why declaration of a parameter was changed so? 
I mean - it works. But why

```
previewFile(indexPath!)
```

instead of

```
previewFile(path: indexPath!)
```

Comment: Expected parameter type following ":"

Comment: What's wrong with `func previewFile(path: NSIndexPath) { ... }`?

Comment: Basically it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use # for internal argument naming anymore. You should write the function like:

```
func previewFile(path path: NSIndexPath) {
   // Your code
}
```

Comment: func previewFile(path: NSIndexPath) {
}

Comment: One word "path" ) Thx ...